# Boundary Condition for Specific PDE Problem Implies Zero Coeffecients: Proof $u(x, 0)=c_1+\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}c_2 cos(nx)=0\implies c_1=c_2=0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

I'm just attempting to follow the solution to the wave equation: $u_{tt}=c^2u_{xx}$ with the boundary conditions $u_x(0, t)=u_x(\pi, t)=0$ and the initial conditions $u(x, 0) =0$ and $u_t(x, 0) = cos ^2(x)$.

Eventually, after reaching our general solution by summing all products $X(x)T(t)$ over all eigenvalues, we have: $$c_1 + c_2t + \sum_{n =1}^\infty (c_3cos(nct)+c_4sin(nct)) cos(nx)$$

For $n=1, 2,..., n$. Thus, we try to satisfy our inital conditions. We have:
$u(x, 0)=c_1+\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}c_2 cos(nx)=0$. How does this imply that both $c_1$ and $c_2$ are zero? (This is from two solutions I'm looking at).

Comment: Because $\{\cos(nx)\}_{n \ge 1}$ is a linearly independent set. Alternatively, why don't you take the inner product of both sides with $\cos(mx)$ for $m \in \mathbb{N}$ and see what comes out?